# Is it possible to pre-allocate a variable to CPU/GPU memory in the MexGateway code written in Visual Studio?

Tags: memory, cuda, mex

I'm trying to write a MexGateway code to pass two variables in matlab to the compiled MexFile, copy the variables to a cuda kernel, do the processing and bring back the results to Matlab. I need to use this MexFile in a for loop in matlab.

The problem is that: The two inputs are huge for my application and ONLY one of them (called Device_Data in the following code) is changing in each loop. So, I'm looking for a way to pre-allocate the stable input so that it does not remove from the GPU at each iteration of my for loop. I also need to say that I really need to do it in my visual studio code and make this happen in the MexGateway code (I do not want to do it in Matlab). is there any solution for this?

Here is my code (I have already compiled it. It works fine):

```
    #include <cuda_runtime.h>
    #include "device_launch_parameters.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "cuda.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <mex.h>
    #include "MexFunctions.cuh"




    __global__ void add (int* Device_Data, int* Device_MediumX, int N) {
    int TID = threadIdx.y * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (TID < N) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            Device_Data[i] = Device_Data[i] + Device_MediumX[i];
        }
    }
    }
    void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray* plhs[],
    int nrhs, const mxArray* prhs[]) {

    int N = 128;
    int* MediumX;
    int* Data;
    int* Data_New;

    MediumX = (int*)mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    Data = (int*)mxGetPr(prhs[1]);

    plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(N,1, mxINT32_CLASS, mxREAL);
    Data_New = (int*)mxGetData(plhs[0]);


    int ArrayByteSize = sizeof(int) * N;
    int* Device_MediumX; // device pointer to the X coordinates of the medium
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((int**)&Device_MediumX, ArrayByteSize));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(Device_MediumX, MediumX, ArrayByteSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    int* Device_Data; // device pointer to the X coordinates of the medium
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((int**)&Device_Data, ArrayByteSize));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(Device_Data, Data, ArrayByteSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    dim3 block(N, 1);
    dim3 grid(1);//SystemSetup.NumberOfTransmitter
    add << <grid, block >> > (Device_Data, Device_MediumX, N);

    (cudaMemcpy(Data_New, Device_Data, ArrayByteSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));


    cudaDeviceReset();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, as long as you have the Distributed Computing Toolbox/Parallel computing toolbox of MATLAB.

The toolbox allows to have a thing called `gpuArrays` in normal MATLAB code, but it also has a C interface where you can get and set these MATLAB arrays GPU addresses.

You can find the documentation here:

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/gpu-cuda-and-mex-programming.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav

For example, for the first input to a mex file:

```
mxGPUArray const *dataHandler= mxGPUCreateFromMxArray(prhs[0]); // Can be CPU or GPU, will copy to GPU if its not already there
float  *  d_data = static_cast<float  *>( (float *)mxGPUGetDataReadOnly(dataHandler)); // get the pointer itself (assuming float data)
```

Comment: Thank you. So, if i understood correctly, I need to use your codes instead of "cudaMalloc" and "cudaMemcpy". And, in your code, the  pointer "d_data" will be placed in the global memory and can be passed to a kernel. Right?

Comment: @MoeinMozaffarzadeh yes, `mxGPUCreateFromMxArray` will do the malloc and memcpy to GPU (if needed). `d_data` won't be placed on global memory, its just a `float *`.  For your application, if the data does not change, the best thing is to just allocate it with `my_data=gpuarray(my_data)` on the MATLAB side, so the malloc and memcpy are already done.

Comment: Ok. I just tried "Device_MediumX=gpuArray(MediumX); 
" to transfer MediumX to the GPU, pass MediumX to the MEXFile, but it crashes when i run it. in my Gateway code, I use  Device_MediumX = (int*)mxGetPr(prhs[0]); and pass "Device_MediumX " to the kernel. Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Without full code and error message is hard to tell.

Comment: I understand that the two lines of code you provided works well if the "gpuArray(MediumX)", defined in Matlab, is assigned to"prhs[0]" in MEX code. However, does Device_MediumX (this is the non-varying variable) stays in GPU memory? I mean, your two lines are being repeated at each loop i run my MEXFunction, and If i understood correctly, they are performing malloc and memcpy to GPU. Could you please comment on this?

Comment: @MoeinMozaffarzadeh you did not understood correctly. `mxGPUCreateFromMxArray` will do malloc and memcopy *only* if its `prhs[0]` is on the CPU, if its on the GPU it will just give you the pointer to it. This is what it says in the documentation, reading it is fundamental. `Device_MediumX` stays on GPU, as `Device_MediumX=gpuArray(MediumX);` puts its in the GPU. Unless you do `gather(Device_MediumX)`, this variable is on the GPU.

Comment: Aha, got it now :). Thank you very much for your explanation. The problem is solved now.

Comment: I just tried to use these two codes in my main program (not the one posted here), but i get an error: LNK2001 unresolved external symbol mxGPUCreateFromMxArray
I also get this for mxGPUGetDataReadOnly. 
Any idea why this is happening? I have #include "mxGPUArray.h" in my code, and added "...\Matlab\toolbox\parallel\gpu", "...\Matlab\toolbox\parallel\gpu\extern\include\gpu" and "...\Matlab\extern\include" in the "configuration properties" of my visual studio project.